# Show submitter a Unique Code (Combination of Text & Number) when they submit a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

How can we show submitter any Unique Code (Combination of Text & Number) For eg: AXC5184 & will this value be also saved in entries??

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This is a feature that we have seen a bit of interest in. We are looking at working on this for future releases and you can follow our progress over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/HbL8cn7K).